# Sum all values meeting a criteria for all possible criteria

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table such as the following:

```
a <- data.table(color=c("Red","Blue","Red","Green","Red","Blue","Blue"), count=c(1,2,6,4,2,1,1),include=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1))

> a
     color count include
[1,]   Red     1       1
[2,]  Blue     2       1
[3,]   Red     6       1
[4,] Green     4       1
[5,]   Red     2       0
[6,]  Blue     1       0
[7,]  Blue     1       1
```

I wish to create a new data.table which has only the unique colour values, and a sum of the count column for each of these that match include=1, like the below:

```
     colour total
[1,]   Red     7
[2,]  Blue     2
[3,] Green     4
```

I have tried the following, which I've had some success with in the past:

```
> a[,include == 1,list(total=sum(count)),by=colour]
Error in `[.data.table`(a, , include == 1, list(quantity = sum(count)),  : 
  Provide either 'by' or 'keyby' but not both
```

This same error message is received when `a` has no key, and when it has a key of `colour`. I have also tried, with the key set to `colour`, the following:

```
> a[,include == 1,list(quantity=sum(count))]
Error in `[.data.table`(a, , include == 1, list(quantity = sum(count))) : 
  Each item in the 'by' or 'keyby' list must be same length as rows in x (7): 1
```

I can't find any other good solutions. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(color=c("Red","Blue","Red","Green","Red","Blue","Blue"), count=c(1,2,6,4,2,1,1),include=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1))
a[include == 1, list(total=sum(count)), keyby = color]

   color total
1:  Blue     3
2: Green     4
3:   Red     7
```

---

Edit from Matthew :

Or if `include` takes (only) values `0` and `1` then :

```
a[, list(total=sum(count*include)), keyby = color]
```

or if `include` includes other values then :

```
a[, list(total=sum(count*(include==1))), keyby = color]
```

where `NA`s may need to be considered.

Those might be more efficient by avoiding the vector scanning `i`, but it depends a lot on data size and properties. These only need working memory as large as the largest group, whereas `include==1` in `i` needs at least one vector allocated as long as `nrow(a)`.

Comment: @Ina So you were out by just one character: the first comma!

Comment: Argh, you're kidding me! Thanks for the help :)