# Sum all values meeting a criteria using data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935962/2142315) using a data frame.

---

Update: 2013/06/14

```
scores <- data.frame( Type=c("Disc","HW","Disc"), Module=c(1,1,2), Score=c(14,6,14))
weights <- data.frame ( Type=c("Disc","HW"), Weight=c(0.2,0.4))
```

I want to apply the weighting factor and sum the *scores* data frame to produce a table that has the weighted sum for each module.  The results should look like:

```
   Module   Weighted Sum
1:      1            5.2
2:      2            2.8
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: question has been updated to fit the format of more traditional Q&A styles I see on the exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying that example:

```
a <- data.frame(color=c("Red","Blue","Red","Green","Red","Blue","Blue"), count=c(1,2,6,4,2,1,1),include=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1))

  color count include
1   Red     1       1
2  Blue     2       1
3   Red     6       1
4 Green     4       1
5   Red     2       0
6  Blue     1       0
7  Blue     1       1

total = sapply(levels(a$color),function(x){sum(a$count[a$color==x & a$include==1])},USE.NAMES=F)

data.frame(color=levels(a$color),total)

  color total
1  Blue     3
2 Green     4
3   Red     7
```